# How to share video file from my internal Download folder to whatsapp

Tags: android, android-intent, fileprovider

As the title already conveyed what I want to achieve, here is what I'm using:

```
public void shareVideoWhatsApp() {
    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("*/*");
    Uri videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(VideoPlayActivity.this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File("storage/emulated/0/Download/test-8.mp4"));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoUri);
    Log.d(getClass().getName()+"__VideoURI", "" + videoUri);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share video using"));

}
```

I'm getting **The file format is not supported** from whatsapp, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use a concrete MIME type, not wildcards. It is your content, so you need to tell the other app what the MIME type is. Also, make sure that your app is able to read this content.

Comment: `As the title already conveyed what I want to achieve,`. Do not refer to the title. You should put all info in your post.